# Small fractional part of powers of a real number

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a positive real number.  For any fixed $\epsilon>0$ does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that fractional part of $p^n$ is less than $\epsilon$?

Add-on: $p$ is rational. (original qn I had in mind).

Comment: This doesn't seem like a bad question to me.  Perhaps those voting to close could say what the answer is?

Comment: The answer is no. Take $p = 2 + \sqrt{2}$ and use the fact that $(2 + \sqrt{2})^n + (2 - \sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer. More generally see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes indeed; I was thinking distance from the nearest integer (which admittedly was not what the OP asked).  Any idea then?

Comment: forgive me for my bad phrasing. Thanks for the answer

Comment: For $p$ rational some googling (http://www.infres.enst.fr/~jsaka/PUB/Files/RBNS-rev.pdf) suggests this is an open problem.